# Apache POI xls file error

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I want to read both `xls` and `xlsx` file format. It is working fine for `xlsx` format but I am getting following error while uploading `xls` file.

#### Code:

```
try {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/apps/" + fileName);
    //POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);

    Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(OPCPackage.open(fileInputStream));
    //XSSFWorkbook workBook1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet ssSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0); 

    Iterator rowIterator = ssSheet.rowIterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row ssRow = (Row) rowIterator.next();
        Iterator iterator = ssRow.cellIterator();
        List cellTempList = new ArrayList();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell ssCell = (Cell) iterator.next();
            cellTempList.add(ssCell);
        }
        cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Error:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:148)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:623)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:230)
```

Please help.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is due to you trying to construct your workbook with the `OPCPackage`, even if you use `WorkbookFactory`. `OPCPackage` "unzip" your `.xlsx` in order to be able to read the xml files inside, but this should not work for HSSF since it is a binary file.

My recomendation would be that you use another constructor such as

`WorkbookFactory.create(InputStream input)`

I guess it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks!! That helped exactly. There was the error. I removed the OPCPackage.

Comment: @mtk how to remove opc package ? i am geeting same exception.

Comment: @Mihir, instead of using XSSFWorkbook, use Workbook (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);)